# Google Sheets API call : request is missing required authentication credential

Tags: oauth2-playground

I have correctly added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets scope to my token, but when I launch my API call to update a simple Google Sheet, I get this error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.AppendValues",
          "service": "sheets.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: du; Name or service not known
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 114
```

Any idea why?

Thanks